# Location service works the opposite way

Tags: thinkpad, location, geolocation

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad T490 with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

When I switch OFF the Location Service in the settings, it determines my location perfectly in the Maps application. If I switch it ON, it does not work anymore. Also, when the service is switched OFF in the settings (switched ON in reality), I cannot see which apps use the location service.

Is this maybe an error with detecting the GPS sensor? How can these sensors be configured in Ubuntu? Did somebody faced the same issue?